# CMake & CodeSynthesis Header-only library not compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, codesynthesis

I have been trying to implement the runtime library which is a header-only library of CodeSynthesis. But I only get a linking compiling error whenever I try to run the generated files which are made by the XSD executable.

Here is the error to show you that I have a linking problem with the runtime library:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable XercesGebeuren.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\XercesGebeuren.dir/objects.a(hello.cxx.obj): in function `xsd::cxx::xml::initialize()':
C:/Users/husey/Desktop/XercesGebeuren/xsd-4.0.0-i686-windows/libxsd/xsd/cxx/xml/elements.hxx:84: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_2::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\XercesGebeuren.dir/objects.a(hello.cxx.obj): in function `xsd::cxx::xml::terminate()':
C:/Users/husey/Desktop/XercesGebeuren/xsd-4.0.0-i686-windows/libxsd/xsd/cxx/xml/elements.hxx:90: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\XercesGebeuren.dir/objects.a(hello.cxx.obj): in function `xsd::cxx::xml::sax::std_input_stream::std_input_stream(std::istream&)':
C:/Users/husey/Desktop/XercesGebeuren/xsd-4.0.0-i686-windows/libxsd/xsd/cxx/xml/sax/std-input-source.hxx:27: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::BinInputStream::BinInputStream()'
---- [And so on] ----
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\XercesGebeuren.dir\build.make:122: XercesGebeuren.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/XercesGebeuren.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/XercesGebeuren.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:137: XercesGebeuren] Error 2
```

I have followed the guide given by CodeSynthesis to generate my hello.cxx & hello.hxx files with the command: `xsd cxx-tree --std c++11 hello.xsd`

**CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(XercesGebeuren)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(Xsd_DIR ./cmake)

find_package(XercesC REQUIRED)
find_package(Xsd REQUIRED)

add_executable(XercesGebeuren main.cpp src/hello.cxx)

add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC INTERFACE "./libxsd/")

target_include_directories(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC ${XSD_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC mylib)
```

Comment: I'm confused. If it's a header-only library, you don't compile it (except as `#include`d source code in your own files). What is `hello.xsd`? What are you trying to do, exactly? What is being built here?

Comment: https://www.codesynthesis.com/mailman/listinfo/xsd-users

Comment: You sir are a genius. I don't have to add it to a library as shown in the CMake example!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings the solution was to remove the add_library and anything that is relevant to it and to link the library XercesC::XercesC to the Project as a target.
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(XercesGebeuren)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(Xsd_DIR ./cmake)

find_package(XercesC REQUIRED)
find_package(Xsd REQUIRED)

add_executable(XercesGebeuren main.cpp src/hello.cxx )

target_include_directories(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC ${XSD_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC XercesC::XercesC)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to 'Asteroids With Wings' I figured out that a header-only library should not be added as a library in CMake.
Including the library and linking the XercesC library was enough.

**CMake solution**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(XercesGebeuren)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(Xsd_DIR ./cmake)

find_package(XercesC REQUIRED)
find_package(Xsd REQUIRED)

add_executable(XercesGebeuren main.cpp src/hello.cxx )

target_include_directories(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC ${XSD_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(XercesGebeuren PUBLIC XercesC::XercesC)
```